# QML add buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, qml

i wrote a simple code and the question is how to add button to first page and not the second page. i've got three calsses (main.qml, componentCreation.js, ButtonD.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import "componentCreation.js" as MyScript

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property var position: 0

    Rectangle{
        id: main
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        x:200
        y:0
        focus: true

        StackView{
            id: stack
            initialItem: firstPage
            Component{
                id: firstPage
                Rectangle{
                    id:firstRect
                    Label{
                        text: "firstPage"
                        x:100
                    }
                    Button{
                        text: "next"
                        onClicked:{
                            MyScript.createSpriteObjects(position)
                            position+=50
                            stack.push(secondPage)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Component{
                id: secondPage
                Rectangle{
                    id:secondRect
                    Label{
                        text: "secondPage"
                        x:100
                    }
                    Button{
                        text: "back"
                        onClicked: stack.push(firstPage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

javaScript code as described in qt website(componentCreation.js)

```
    var component;
    var sprite;
    function createSpriteObjects(number) {
        component = Qt.createComponent("ButtonD.qml");
        if (component.status == Component.Ready)
            finishCreation(number);
        else
            component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
    }
    function finishCreation(number) {
        if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
            sprite = component.createObject(main, {"x": 50, "y": number});
            number += 50
            if (sprite == null) {
                console.log("Error creating object");
            }
        } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
            console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
        }
    }
```

the button i want to add

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
Button{
    text: "created"
}
```

Comment: A minimal example would help. It seems like the answer depends on code that we don't have access to.

Comment: added qml code...

Comment: `createObject()` is overall confusing. Try to use data models and repeaters instead.

Comment: The code isn't complete. Please provide a minimal, complete example.

Comment: i wrote a sample code

Answer (score 0):

> what should I write in
>
> ```
> sprite = component.createObject(main, {"x": 100, "y": 500});
> ```
>
> instead of main? i want to add a button from the javascript code to the rectangle with id secondRect

That first parameter to createObject is the id of the item you want to add the object to, so isn't the answer secondRect?

Comment: nope, "ReferenceError: secondRect is not defined" is the error

Answer (score 0):

Well, like Mitch already pointed out your example code is not complete.

However, I **think** the problem is that `finishCreation()` function does not know about 'main' id.

```
var component;
var sprite;

    function createSpriteObjects() {
        component = Qt.createComponent("ButtonD.qml");
        if (component.status == Component.Ready)
            finishCreation();
        else
            component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
    }

    function finishCreation() {
        if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
            sprite = component.createObject(main, {"x": 100, "y": 500});
            if (sprite == null) {
                // Error Handling
                console.log("Error creating object");
            }
        } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
        }
    }
```

So maybe you should pass the reference to the functions above (untested):

```
    var component;
    var sprite;

        function createSpriteObjects(parentId) {
            component = Qt.createComponent("ButtonD.qml");
            if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
              if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
               sprite = component.createObject(parentId, {"x": 100, "y": 500});
               if (sprite == null) {
                 // Error Handling
                console.log("Error creating object");
               }
             } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
                // Error Handling
                console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
             }                
          } else {
                var thatParentId = parentId;
                component.statusChanged.connect(function() {
                  if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
                   sprite = component.createObject(thatParentId, {"x": 100, "y": 500});
                    if (sprite == null) {
                      // Error Handling
                      console.log("Error creating object");
                    }
                  } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
                     // Error Handling
                     console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
                  }    
                });
         }
     }
```

After that you can call `MyScripts.createSpriteObjects(secondRect);`

Comment: Could you please apply my code into your sample project? In your edited answer I do not see that you have used my code.

Comment: Button{
                        text: "next"
                        onClicked:{
                            MyScript.createSpriteObjects(secondPage)
                            position+=50
                            stack.push(secondPage)
                        }
                    }                   //////                                                                                       componentCreation.js is as you've written and this is how i call it and it says:  Created graphical object was not placed in the graphics scene.

Comment: Well, this is because 'secondPage' is an id of an unloaded component. So please try 'MyScript.createSpriteObjects(stack.currentItem)' AFTER calling 'stack.push'

Comment: it won't add anything